# Converting code containing views to stored procedure

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, view

I've pieced together this code to create a pivot on a sum of invoice subtotals per a dealership. It works, and produces the correct results. However, when I try to convert it to a stored procedure the infamous squiggly red line appears under "CREATE VIEW Revenues" in SQL Server management studio and the error says:

'CREATE VIEW must be the only statement in the batch' and I don't know enough T-SQL to proceed as I need to be able to execute it from a ASP.NET/C# web app.

I'm trying create an SP by putting:

1)

```
USE [Sherwood]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE PROC [dbo].[usp_GetRevenues] 

@StartDate AS DateTime = '20120301',
@EndDate AS DateTime = '20120401'
AS
SET NOCOUNT ON;

BEGIN
```

in front, with an END statement at the end.

2) The parameters are necessary to be able to filter the data for a period of months, but I appear not to be able to pass parameters or use variables with the code as is.

Thanks in advance.

Code as is below - showing where I need to filter with variables. The code works only with dates in the format '1/1/2012' in the where clause, but need to be able to pass variables as shown.

--================================

```
CREATE VIEW Revenues
AS
SELECT  
i.DateOrdered
,LTRIM(STR(DATEPART(MONTH,i.DateOrdered))) AS [Month]  
,LTRIM(STR(YEAR(i.Dateordered))) AS [Year]  
,c.CustomerCode
,SUM(i.Jobprice) AS Subtotal 
FROM Invoices i
JOIN
Customers c
ON i.CustomerID = c.ID
WHERE i.DateOrdered >= @StartDate 
AND i.DateOrdered <= @EndDate **<-- and here.**  
GROUP BY ROLLUP (YEAR(i.DateOrdered), 
MONTH(i.DateOrdered), i.DateOrdered, c.CustomerCode);
GO

IF OBJECT_ID('Revenues2') IS NOT NULL
DROP VIEW Revenues2
GO

CREATE VIEW Revenues2
AS
SELECT 
 LTRIM(STR([YEAR])) + '-' + STUFF([Month],1,0, REPLICATE('0', 2 - LEN([Month]))) 
 AS [Date] 
,Subtotal
,CustomerCode
FROM Revenues
WHERE CustomerCode IS NOT NULL
GO

DECLARE @query VARCHAR(4000)  
DECLARE @years VARCHAR(2000)  
SELECT  @years = STUFF(( SELECT DISTINCT 
                    '],[' + [Date]  
                    FROM  Revenues2 
                    ORDER BY '],[' + [Date]  
                    FOR XML PATH('')  
                    ), 1, 2, '') + ']' 

SET @query =  
'SELECT * FROM  
(  
  SELECT Subtotal,[Date],CustomerCode  
   FROM Revenues2  
)t  
PIVOT (SUM(Subtotal) FOR [Date] 
IN ('+ @years +')) AS pvt' 

EXECUTE (@query)
```

--==========================================

Regards

Cliff

Comment: Which version of SQL SERVER are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I may be wrong, but it seems to me you're not deleting/commenting the "CREATE VIEW" part when you're converting to an SP. This is wrong for you cannot define a view from within a stored procedure's definition - hence the "CREATE VIEW must be(...)" complaint.

Besides, that code of yours is a bit fragile: once you've correctly created the SP, next time it runs it will error with a message of "The SP is already used, you should be using ALTER PROC" or something like that (I'm writing from memory know).

Code like this should solve both problems:

```
USE [Sherwood]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

-- It's preferable to set these options before creating an SP,
-- rather than within its execution
SET NOCOUNT ON
GO
IF OBJECT_ID('usp_GetRevenues') IS NOT NULL
    DROP PROC usp_GetRevenues
GO
CREATE PROC [dbo].[usp_GetRevenues] 
    @StartDate AS DateTime = '20120301',
    @EndDate AS DateTime = '20120401' AS
-- BEGIN --This is really optional
SELECT  
i.DateOrdered
,LTRIM(STR(DATEPART(MONTH,i.DateOrdered))) AS [Month]  
,LTRIM(STR(YEAR(i.Dateordered))) AS [Year]  
,c.CustomerCode
,SUM(i.Jobprice) AS Subtotal 
FROM dbo.Invoices i
JOIN dbo.Customers c
ON i.CustomerID = c.ID
WHERE i.DateOrdered >= @StartDate 
AND i.DateOrdered <= @EndDate **<-- and here.**  
GROUP BY ROLLUP (YEAR(i.DateOrdered), 
MONTH(i.DateOrdered), i.DateOrdered, c.CustomerCode);
GO
```

Comment: I create the views, because I have to perform actions on the data set from the prior SELECT statement. Do I create and drop temporary tables or what is the best way to handle this scenario, and could you give me some idea how it would be coded - as I don't know - hence the views. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You could try this using temp tables instead.

Something like

```
SELECT   
i.DateOrdered 
,LTRIM(STR(DATEPART(MONTH,i.DateOrdered))) AS [Month]   
,LTRIM(STR(YEAR(i.Dateordered))) AS [Year]   
,c.CustomerCode 
,SUM(i.Jobprice) AS Subtotal  
INTO #Revenues
FROM Invoices i 
JOIN 
Customers c 
ON i.CustomerID = c.ID 
WHERE i.DateOrdered >= @StartDate  
AND i.DateOrdered <= @EndDate **<-- and here.**   
GROUP BY ROLLUP (YEAR(i.DateOrdered),  
MONTH(i.DateOrdered), i.DateOrdered, c.CustomerCode)

SELECT  
 LTRIM(STR([YEAR])) + '-' + STUFF([Month],1,0, REPLICATE('0', 2 - LEN([Month])))  
 AS [Date]  
,Subtotal 
,CustomerCode 
INTO #Revenues2
FROM #Revenues 
WHERE CustomerCode IS NOT NULL 

DECLARE @query VARCHAR(4000)   
DECLARE @years VARCHAR(2000)   
SELECT  @years = STUFF(( SELECT DISTINCT  
                    '],[' + [Date]   
                    FROM  #Revenues2  
                    ORDER BY '],[' + [Date]   
                    FOR XML PATH('')   
                    ), 1, 2, '') + ']'  

SET @query =   
'SELECT * FROM   
(   
  SELECT Subtotal,[Date],CustomerCode   
   FROM #Revenues2   
)t   
PIVOT (SUM(Subtotal) FOR [Date]  
IN ('+ @years +')) AS pvt'  

EXECUTE (@query)

DROP TABLE #Revenues
DROP TABLE #Revenues2
```

Comment: Temp tables. Great idea and it almost compiles. I get a syntax error on the SELECT statement inside the SET @query line 56. The actual error is Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure usp_GetRevenues, Line 56 Incorrect syntax near 'END'.

Comment: Removing the BEGIN and END made all the difference and the temp tables was definitely the way to go - it compiles and runs. Thanks for the help - Cliff